# Quick question: Where is the C++ compiler located in Windows?

Tags: c++, matlab

For some MATLAB code that I want to make executable, I need the location to a compiler in Windows.  I have Visual Studio installed, so would I be able to reference the compiler that that uses? If so, how can I find it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just keep in mind that most users don't have a compiler in a windows environment.

Comment: The OP did specify that Visual Studio is installed - provided it's a C++ version, it should be there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the "Visual Studio Command Prompt", and you'll have the environment setup for compilation.

Comment: Or if you need to start the shell from MatLab not the shortcut Reed mentioned, run vcvars.bat, which will set the environment correctly to compile.

Comment: After running it, I realized where the cl.exe file is, and was able to  use that path successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to Run the "Visual Studio Command Prompt". When you install Visual Studio, it sets the environment variable: `VS90COMNTOOLS`.

Using that variable, you can figure out that `"%VS90COMNTOOLS%....\VC\bin"` points to the directory that contains the compiler. So to invoke the compiler you can use: `"%VS90COMNTOOLS%....\VC\bin\cl.exe"`.

Note the use quotes. This is because the `VS90COMNTOOLS` has spaces in it if you take the default install location under `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles%(x86)`.